# Casting vector of base class to derived class

Tags: c++, oop, casting, polymorphism

I have an abstract class named **Goods**. 
Based on this class I derive others such as **Potatoes**, **Toys**, **Wine**.

```
Beer 
    b1(/*price*/ 4, 
       /*quantity*/ 1000, 
       /*type*/ "red", 
       /*name*/ "Skolls"),

    b2(/*price*/ 3.5, 
       /*quantity*/ 1000, 
       /*type*/ "blonde", 
       /*name*/ "Braun");

Potatoes
    p1(/*price*/ 2,
        /*quantity*/ 1000,
        /*type*/ "red"),

    p2(/*price*/ 2,
        /*quantity*/ 1000,
        /*type*/ "white");

Wine
    w1(/*price*/ 4.5,
        /*quantity*/ 1000,
        /*name*/ "Chavignon",
        /*origin*/ "France",
        /*year*/ 2000),

Market market;

market.Consumer.push_back(&b1);
market.Consumer.push_back(&b2);
market.Consumer.push_back(&p1);
market.Consumer.push_back(&p2);
market.Consumer.push_back(&w1);
```

I added them in a vector named Consumer declared like this:

```
std::vector<Goods*> Consumer
```

What I can't figure out is how can I cast each element from Consumer to its Derived equivalent in a **for** statement like this, so that I can apply some specific methods based on the derived class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Consumer.size(); i++) {
     Wine* Consumer[i] = static_cast<Goods*>(Consumer[i]);
```

When I try to do it as above, I get an error regarding the value of i : "expression must have a constant value"

### Goods.H

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//Base class
class Goods
{
protected:
    double Price;
    double Quantity;

public:
    virtual void setprice(double prc) = 0;
    virtual double getprice() const = 0;

    virtual void setquantity(double qty) = 0;
    virtual double getquantity() const = 0;

    virtual std::string getID() const = 0;

    virtual void print() = 0;

    Goods();
    Goods(double prc, double qty);
    ~Goods();
};
```

Comment: Use polymorphism to achieve your goal.

Comment: @ElvisOric, I already have virtual (pure) functions, that (in my example) are getters and setters for each derived class. What you mean is adding other virtual functions that I will later override in the derived classes?

Comment: Well, what do you want to perform, override that operation in your derived classes.

Comment: Re: "I already have virtual ... functions" -- not in the code you've shown. Nobody can give you a useful answer from code fragments.

Comment: @PeteBecker it's a long code with lots of headers and full of other technical details. I was trying to be as clear and concise as possible.

Comment: Leaving out essential details is not being clear and concise. Surely some of that long code with lots of headers can be removed without spoiling the question. In fact, with a little effort, I’ll bet you could come up with a small example of what you’ve tried that didn’t work. That’s how good questions get written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this I think would be to use inheritance and runtime-polymorphism. You have your base class `Goods` which declares an interface (though pure virtual methods) which is then implemented by your derived classes (such as `Wine`).

This means you do not have to do any casting in order to use your custom behaviour, you do not even need to know what *type* your pointer actually points too, simply that it inherits from `Goods` and must implement its interface.

This allows you to write code like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < Consumer.size(); i++) {
     Goods* consumer = Consumer[i];
     consumer->/* some pure virtual method in Goods, will call the overridden method in whatever object consumer points too */
```

This does have the limitation that you cannot call methods which are not declared in `Goods`. However it is much safer than attempting to perform a cast without knowing without *any* doubt what the real type is.

If you *really* want to cast all the objects to a different type you can do it with either `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, of the two neither are very pretty but if you can guarentee through some logic that the type in in fact what you are attempting to cast it too, use `static_cast`, if not use `dynamic_cast` (on an incorrect cast `static_cast` is UB, `dynamic_cast` will return a `nullptr`)

To do this you could do something like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < Consumer.size(); i++) {
     auto* consumer = dynamic_cast<Wine*>(Consumer[i]);
     some_other_vector.emplace_back(consumer); // Assuming your other vector starts empty
```

I have used `dynamic_cast` here, really you should also check whether `consumer` is also valid. Using `static_cast` will bypass the runtime overhead of `dynamic_cast` but it should *almost* never be used when casting to a derived type.

Comment: So, there's no way to do that with casting? Only through other pure virtual methods?

Comment: If you want to access methods not defined in the type you are accessing them through (In this case `Goods`) then no, you cannot. However based on your example it looks like you do not need to do this and/or you could easily change your code to utilise runtime polymorphism instead

Comment: @FusiFlag Sorry just realised what you meant :p, I have updated my answer with a way to do this through casting

Comment: what is "some_other_vector" supposed to be? what kind of vector? because if it's a copy of Consumer then it's the same situation as before. still can't access derived specific methods

Comment: do I need to initialise one for each type of derived object? e.g  `std::vector<Wine*> cpy_w`, `std::vector<Toys*> cpy_t` and so on?

Comment: _If_ you want to do it like that then yes you do, this is one of the reasons why I suggest _not_ doing it like that

Comment: The program crashes when it reaches `some_other_vector[i] = consumer`.  "Debug Assertion Failed"                                    EDIT:: change `some_other_vector[i] = consumer` to `some_other_vector.pushback(consumer)`

Comment: Yep sorry, shoudlve clarified that, you will need to reserve the space in `some_other_vector` (with `resize`) first, use `push_back` or preferably `emplace_back` if you do not want to do that